# Merging/Creating powerpoint slides in PHP using COM and PHPPowerpoint

Tags: php, com, merge, powerpoint

My requirement is to split ppt/pptx files and then merge particular slides.

I have successfully split ppt/pptx files into seperate slides using PHP COM. Now I want to join/merge the slides using some PHP Library.

However, there doesn't seem to be one except PHPPowerpoint.

I can use PHPPowerpoint to create slides and add text nodes/images using it but it cannot read existing .ppt/pptx files and create a merged output.

Is there another way? I will appreciate any help at all.

EDIT:
I was able to merge slides but not Properly.. the background color/sort order is still missing. Please help as there are no references on the web on this except for this link -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746640%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Here is the code -

```
        //SET Max exec time
        ini_set("max_execution_time",-1);


        $directory = 'c:/ppt/slides/';
        $files_list = array_diff(scandir($directory,SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING), array('..', '.')); //Get list of all files from the sub slides folder
        //var_dump($files_list); die;
        $ppt_new = new COM("powerpoint.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Powerpoint 2");
        $ppt_new->Presentations->Add(true); //Create the new(merged) ppt
        $dirpath = "C:/ppt/slides/";        
        $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Slides->Add( 1, 1 );
        foreach($files_list as $file) { //Loop through all slides to merge those

        $powerpnt = new COM("powerpoint.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Powerpoint");
                echo "Adding slide...";
                echo $file_path1 = realpath($dirpath.$file);

                $pres = $powerpnt->Presentations->Open($file_path1, false, false, false) or die("Unable to open the slide");
                echo $count = (int)$pres->Slides->Count."<--SLIDES COUNT<br>";
                $i=1;
                foreach($pres->Slides as $slide)

                {   
                try {
                    $pptLayout = $slide->CustomLayout;
//                  var_dump($pptLayout); die;
//                  $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Slides[$i]->FollowMasterBackground  = false;
//                  $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Slides[$i]->Background = $slide->Background;
                    //$ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Slides->Layout = $pptLayout;

                    $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Slides->InsertFromFile($file_path1, $i, $i, $i);
                    //          $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->SaveAs("merged11.ppt");
                    //          $ppt_new->Export("created.ppt", "ppt");
                    $i++;
                    }
                        catch(Exception $e)
                        {
                            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
                        } 
                }

        }

        //Save the merged presentation
        $powerpnt->quit();
        $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->SaveAs("c:\ppt\merged121.ppt");
        $ppt_new->Presentations[1]->Close(); 
        $ppt_new->quit();

        echo "Done!";
```

Can anyone please run the code and find why the background is not coming in the merged slide?
Thanks already.

Comment: As PHPPowerPoint doesn't can't be used for what you want;  it looks like you'll have to use COM (if you're on a Windows server), or Open/Libre Office with [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)

Comment: @MarkBaker Is it possible for you to provide with an example using COM? I was unable to find one for merging ppts

Comment: I don't use COM, so I can't give an example: as one of the development team behind the PHPOffice suite of libraries (that includes PHPPowerPoint) I believe in using my own code, and I've not had any need to merge slides from different presentations before

Comment: @MarkBaker I have added code in COM to merge slides but the background is not appearing and the slides are not sorted in order. Can you have a look please?

Comment: If you can't find a library to help you to do it in PHP, you can do it in Java or .NET with the Enterprise Edition of docx4j/pptx4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I followed this link http://skp.mvps.org/pptxp001.htm and manually converted the example code in VBA  into PHP. Basically the InsertFromFile() method was not working properly so I used Copy() and Paste() methods as per the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746640%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The library `cristal/pptx` can do exactly what you want to do. It's a pure PHP library without any dependandy to Powerpoint, which can read existing PPTX and manipulate slides respecting the original format.

```php
<?php

use Cristal\Presentation\PPTX;

$fooPPTX = new PPTX(__DIR__.'/asset/foo.pptx');
$barPPTX = new PPTX(__DIR__.'/asset/bar.pptx');

$fooPPTX->addSlides($barPPTX->getSlides());

$fooPPTX->saveAs(__DIR__.'/dist/result.pptx');
```

https://github.com/CristalTeam/pptx